# Basic use of std::range similar to iota

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I’m trying to use std ranges for the first time. I have a few arrays, I use them to generate std::vector of std::string_view’s:

```
static std::vector<std::string_view> x;

const char data[] = "1231234567812345";
const int offsets[] = { 0, 3, 11 };
const int sizes[] = { 3, 8, 5 };

const std::vector<std::string_view>& getRange()
{
    if (x.empty())
    {
        x.resize(sizeof(sizes) / sizeof(sizes[0]));
        for (size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i)
            x[i] = std::string_view(data + offsets[i], data + offsets[i] + sizes[i]);
    }
    return x;
}
```

Users of the getRange simply want to be able to iterate elements, get size of the sequence and to access elements using operator[]. As I understand, this code could be a good candidate to change the code to use ranges, so that instead of generating vector of string views, I could use range that generates the string views lazily when requested (similarly to ranges::iota).
What should I use to generate such range from these arrays without creating intermediary vector?

**Update:**

This seems to work:

```
auto sv = [](int i) { return std::string_view(data + offsets[i], data + offsets[i] + sizes[i]); };
auto rangeView = std::views::iota(0u, sizeof(sizes) / sizeof(sizes[0])) | std::views::transform(sv);
```

`rangeView` is now functionally equivalent to `getRange`. [See the code on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0da70755a556c9b).

In my case getRange is declared in .h, and defined in .cpp file. Can do the same with `rangeView`?

Comment: Since the `string_view`s don't own the memory you would need to store the actual strings that you generate too.

Comment: Strings aren't generated. The string_views point into the `data` array.

Comment: Seems like you are looking into [std::ranges::view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view) Anyway alg seems really compliacted what do you trying to accomplish i.e. build mesh from something like COLLADA file ? Or permutations etc ? Are there any examples how result should looks like ?

Comment: I looked into [iota](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view) and it appears to inherit from [view_interface](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view_interface). Looks easy enough to impl it, however, I need to impl iterator myself and that's painful in c++. In all these years there is still no easy way to do it (std::iterator is deprecated now).

Comment: _"The string_views point into the `data` array"_ - Ok. Are the offsets and sizes known at compile-time or are they runtime values? And just because `std::iterator` is deprecated it doesn't mean you can't use it. It's still in the standard library. It doesn't provide much help other than a couple of `typedef`s though. That part is rarely the hard part when it comes to implementing iterators.

Comment: The example shows it all. One other option I see is `iota(0, size) | transform(i => string_view)` if transform view can transform from one element type to another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++23 has [`std::views::zip_transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/zip_transform_view) for this:

```
auto getRange() {
    return std::views::zip_transform(
        [](int offset, int size) {
            return std::string_view(data + offset, data + offset + size);
        },
        offsets, sizes);
}
```

In C++20, the same can be achieved using [`std::views::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view) to generate input range for [`std::views::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view):

```
auto getRangeOld() {
    return std::views::iota(std::size_t{}, std::size(sizes)) |
           std::views::transform([](std::size_t i) {
               return std::string_view(data + offsets[i],
                                       data + offsets[i] + sizes[i]);
           });
}
```

[See it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/94hsW8sxT)

Minor caveat: if you ever allow the ranges to be of different size, `getRange` automatically gets minimal size of all the ranges. `getRangeOld` will have UB if `sizes` is larger than `offsets`, though the remedy is simple `std::min`.

If `data` can be `std::string_view`, you can use `dataStringView.substr()` method instead to get substrings more safely - if `offsets[i] + sizes[i]` is greater than `std::size(data)`, you'd have UB. `dataStringView.substr(offsets[i], sizes[i])` is both easier to read and safe from the UB.

And final note: I don't know if this is actually more performant than your current implementation. Ranges are somewhat new addition and they may or may be well optimised by the compiler. Test and check if the ranges version is actually better in your environment or not. Now I come to think of this, you can also make it a global `constexpr` object of view type instead of generating it on the fly - may be a little bit easier without the extra function around it.

Comment: iota+transform is the approach I tried and it works as long as I leave it all inside the header (I added that in my question). How can I export the range though from .cpp?

Comment: @PavelP That's... surprisingly difficult. As much as I love C++ being a statically and strongly typed language, in this case it makes simple code horribly ugly: https://godbolt.org/z/McbhqYPa3 At this point, it seems better to move `getRangeOld` definition to header and expose `data`/`offsets`/`sizes` in the `detail` namespace as `export` or `inline` variables. Or create a wrapper to view that's only satisfying `std::input_range` and forwards calls to the stored view.

Comment: That's the part I was looking for `auto getRangeOld() -> std::ranges::transform_view<detail::RangeType, detail::FunctionType>;
`. Really hard to figure out all that stuff with ranges. I guess, I'd better stick with all style C++ :)

Comment: @PavelP Basically, you have to do the compiler's job and write out specific types. And with ranges that basically requires writing entire implementation in `decltype` or typing out every result of every range step - the more stuff happens in the implementation, the more types you have to write. I don't think ranges were really meant to be used this way by the standard committee - and they specifically omitted `ranges::any_range` to make it even more difficult.

Comment: @PavelP Also, a possible improvement of the non-range method: put the body of `if` in a `makeRange` function (or an immediately invoked lambda) that is used to initialise the vector and then `getRange` is simply `return x;`. You avoid having to check the condition every call.